# Excel VBA Changing Cell Color

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I am trying to get all the cells that in column U which NOT equal to 2.04 or 3.59 to change cell color.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Cell_Color_Change()

For Each cell In Range("U2:U19004")
    If cell.Value <> 2.04 Or 3.59 Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Next cell

End Sub
```

The code turn the whole column red for some reasons.
I have tried using the conditional formatting, same thing happened.
Please help. Thank you!

Comment: You're using the wrong logic operator. If you want cells that equal 2.04 or 3.59 to change colour you should use the `=` operator. Also, you need to compare it twice i.e `cell.value = 2.04 or cell.value = 3.59`

Comment: I am sorry Brotato. I meant to say NOT equal to. My bad. Thank you!

Comment: It's been a while since I've used VBA, but try `If cell.Value <> 2.04 Or cell.Value <> 3.59 Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3`

Comment: I believe that by not adding an operator in the second part, VBA will treat the number as true, because anything other than 0 is true, and it will always happen

Comment: I would avoid using Color.Index, since a use can change themes and then your Color can change.  So under one theme, Color.Index(1) may be Orange, but under another it may be Blue.  I suggest always using RGB values when setting colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct your `AND` and `OR`:

```
Private Sub Cell_Color_Change()
    For Each cell In Range("U2:U19004")
        If cell.Value <> 2.04 And cell.Value <> 3.59 Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Next cell
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To look for values rounded to two decimal digits, try this alternative:

```
Private Sub Cell_Color_Change()

    Dim cv As Variant

    For Each cell In Range("U2:U19004")
        cv = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(cell.Value, 2)
        If cv <> 2.04 And cv <> 3.59 Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: How did you do that? I had the same code originally. But it still highlighting the whole column. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: @CiaraMo  You may be the victim of round-off error..............the values in column **U** may not ***EXACTLY*** match your criteria! *(especially if they come from formulas)*

Comment: They do come from a formula. It is a sum() function there. What can I fix it then?

Comment: I fixed it! I locked all the float number to only 2 decimal places. Now it works like a charm! Thank you so much! @Gary's Student :)

Comment: @CiaraMo  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Thank you so much! 1 more thing tho. It is possible to have it run automatically? Because now when I updated the spreadsheet and the cell changed, the color would not change unless I run the code manually. Is there any way that I can get it changing the color once the cell value has changed?

Comment: @CiaraMo If you want it to update automatically you probably want to use conditional formatting.

Comment: @Gary's Student Oh yeah, conditional formatting doesn't work before was because of the mismatch decimal places. Now we have it fixed. Conditional formatting now is working! Appreciate for all the help!!!! Take care :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Conditional Formatting will do this:
   a. use the formula: `AND(U2<>2.04,U2<>3.59)`
   b. Choose your fill color
   c. Apply it to `U2:U19004`
2. But if you want to code it the if should be:

   `If cell.Value <> 2.04 AND cell.Value <> 3.59 Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3`

Answer (score 0):

Set Conditional Formatting with VBA.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub set_Cell_Color_Change()

    With Range("U2:U19004")
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=and(round($u2, 2)<>2.04, round($u2, 2)<>3.59)"
        .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Font.Color = vbRed
    End With

End Sub
```